# How to read dat file in R which is having different seperators

Tags: r

Here is the sample dataset. Here the problem is the seperator is `::` but inbetween the movie name there is `:` so I am getting problem with this.
Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do the following:

```
require(data.table)
input <- data.table(do.call(rbind,strsplit(readLines('file.txt'),'::' )))
input[, c("V3", "V4", "V5") := tstrsplit(V3, split = "|", fixed = T)]
```

The first line reads your file ("file.txt" should be substituted with your file name) using the :: as a separator. The second line splits the 1 column that contains all the classifications into 3 separate columns.

Comment: glad to hear it :)